# How to use INDEX / MATCH together?

Tags: excel-formula

Hello i'm wanting to remove the sheet '01' and point at AH1 which has my sheet name in.

I seem to have got the first part of the formula right for the array. But no matter what i try i cannot seem to get the other 2 working.

This is for a forecasting file that works week on week

Current Code

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&AH$1&"'!$1:$1048576"),MATCH([@SKU],'01'!$D:$D,0),MATCH(AJ$4,'01'!$4:$4,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be similar to the first:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&AH$1&"'!$1:$1048576"),MATCH([@SKU],INDIRECT("'"&AH$1&"'!$D:$D),0),MATCH(AJ$4,INDIRECT("'"&AH$1&"'!$4:$4),0))
```